# Поиск задач по дате последнего обновления в плагине Jira

Tags: java, плагин, jira

Пишу плагин для Jira.

Для поиска по проекту использую IssueManager, там есть методы поиска только по id, списку id, можно получить список id задач по проекту... но нет методов поиска по атрибутам задачи.

Подскажите как можно найти все задачи которые были обновлены после заданной даты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, данной задачи - привожу решение может кому-нибудь будет интересно

```
@Component
public class Utils{

    @ComponentImport
    private SearchProvider searchProvider;

    @ComponentImport
    private UserManager userManager;

    @ComponentImport
    private IssueManager issueManager;


    @Inject
    public Utils( IssueManager issueManager, UserManager userManager, SearchProvider searchProvider ){
        this.issueManager = issueManager;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.searchProvider = searchProvider;
        ...
    }

    ...

    public List<Issue> getIssuesByDateUpdateAfter( Date dTime ) throws SearchException{
        JqlQueryBuilder builder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();
        builder.where().addDateCondition( IssueFieldConstants.UPDATED, Operator.GREATER_THAN_EQUALS, dTime );
        return searchIssues( builder.buildQuery() );
    }

    public List<Issue> searchIssues( Query query ){
        ApplicationUser user = userManager.getUserByName( username );
        SearchQuery searchQuery = SearchQuery.create( query, user );
        IssueIdCollector collector = new IssueIdCollector();
        try{
            ThreadLocalSearcherCache.startSearcherContext();
            searchProvider.search( searchQuery, collector );
        }catch( Exception e ){
            e.getMessage();
        }finally{
            ThreadLocalSearcherCache.stopAndCloseSearcherContext();
        }
        return searchIssues(collector);
    }

    public List<Issue> searchIssues(IssueIdCollector collector){
        Set<String> strIds = collector.getIssueIds();
        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        for( String strId : strIds ){
            ids.add( Long.parseLong( strId ) );
        }
        return issueManager.getIssueObjects( ids );
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял суть, то можно получить запросы используя ScriptRunner и JQL

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchQuery
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.parser.JqlQueryParser
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.query.IssueIdCollector
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import java.util.List;

def query = "project = \"Test\""   
List<Issue> issues = getIssuesByJQL(query)

def List getIssuesByJQL(String jql) {
    def jqlQueryParser = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(JqlQueryParser)
    def searchProvider = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchProvider)
    def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
    def user = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByName("loginTest");
    def query = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery(jql)
    def iManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
    IssueIdCollector collector = new IssueIdCollector()
    SearchQuery searchQuery = SearchQuery.create(query, user)
    searchProvider.search(searchQuery, collector)
    return collector.getIssueIds().collect { iManager.getIssueObject(it as Long) }
}
```

Вот пример, по сути Вам остается только подставить нужный проект, JQL и юзера

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ScriptRunner не использую, но он натолкнул на нужные мысли.